# A flag in the Off Topic flag menu that shouldn't be there?

Tags: discussion, flagging, scope

When I open the *Flag* menu for a question or answer and select the *Closing -> Off-Topic* I see the next possible flag:

> This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

[image: Four flag in the Off-Topic menu]

IMO this discription is very useful but it doesn't fit on the *off-topic* at all.

Are you agree? Shouldn't this be moved from there?

Comment: This is part of the new closing changes.  Since they removed TL they moved most of what it covered under OT.

Comment: Right. But in this case I think that *they were* a bit off-topic (sounds recursive)

Comment: Yes,  everyone agrees with you, but what are we supposed to replace it with?

Comment: I'm not saying that this should be replaced, but *moved*. This could be moved into the *parent* menu.

Comment: I think that it fits in the parent menu (Closing), since the action is `Closing`, the question is *clossed* because, blah, blah, blah, not *closing because is off-topic and is off-topic because blah, blah, blah*

Comment: @Braiam Yes I'm agree. Because *blah, blah, blah*..

Comment: @Lucio, shouldn't this be tagged as [tag:feature-request]? or a new question for that?

Comment: This has been noticed on many sites: [Shouldn't “off-topic” be only about… off-topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on Ask Ubuntu, we have a page dedicated to explaining what is on- and off-topic: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Nowhere on that page does it mention that problems of this type are off-topic. So either that help page should be updated to say that such problems are off-topic, or the flag should be moved to a different flagging section.

Comment: The flag should be moved, but it seems that the people that have to do it are comfortable with it.

Comment: @Lucio It *can't* be moved without changes to the system. Custom close reasons are *all* only listed under off-topic.

Comment: @FEichinger which is wrong